# Battery size to power a 240v 35watt fan for 12 hours and what size/ power solar panel to recharge it?

Tags: batteries, ac, solar-cell, fan

I'm a real novice when it comes to electrical engineering. Like a fish out of water. I want to create a self-sustaining fan for summer.

I'm trying a fan that's 240V, 35W. If I was going to run it for 8 hours, what size or power battery would I need? What would be the most efficient size/power solar panel to recharge it?

Comment: Question title says 12 hours. Short answer is your battery will probably be a couple of kilograms so if you're going to be carrying it around you may want to reconsider.

Comment: you probably want to reconsider a DC fan to improve motor efficiency matched to a Wh or VAh  battery source i.e. car battery and a PV matched for your solar power avail/day probably >4x fan power

Comment: similar: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36273/powering-10watt-light-bulb-for-24-hours-using-solar-power and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/204794/calculation-of-solar-panel-and-battery

Answer (score 1):

35W for 12 hours is 420 W*hr. One Li-ion 18650 cell (same as in many laptops) has capacity of about 10 W*hr. So you will need about 50 cells to keep your fan running for 12 hours. Each cell is about 45g, so the whole battery will weight about 2.2 kg, or about 5 lbs.

Now about solar. As I understand, you likely want to recharge your battery over one day, ready for another 12 hours. To recharge a 420 Wh battery over a daylight time, say 6 hours, your will need at least a 100-W solar panel, something like used for RV or boat, [example on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/100-Watt-100W-Solar-Panel-Kit-with-LCD-Solar-Controller-12V-RV-Boat-Off-Grid-/281308006185). The thing will have 40" x 26" x 1.2" in size, and weight of 19 lbs (8.5 kg). Most likely you will need a bigger panel, since this one makes only 300 Wh over a sunny day, so you might need to double the panels.

ADDITION: I forgot to mention that in order to"create" a self-sustainable solar power system, you will also need:

(a) solar controller/stabilizer;

(b) balanced battery charger (to charge all cells evenly);

(c) power management electronics, to balance input between the charger, battery, and outlets;

(d) durable enclosure with proper connectors/outlets;

(e) mounting harware for solar panel, to follow the Sun, at least manually.

The project will take likely a full year for a team of several engineers.
Alternatively you can shell out some sizable money ($500 - $1000) and get a professionally built product, like the 400 Wh "[Goal Zero Yeti solar station](http://www.goalzero.com/p/165/Goal-Zero-Yeti-400-Solar-Generator)".

Comment: Plus you may want to run the fan while charging, so add solar panel area for that too.

Comment: "The project will take likely a full year for a team of several engineers." ... What is your basis for that comment? The rest of your answer seems great but I don't see where there is multiple man years of work for professionals.