# Will this be able to run 24/7?

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I'm trying to find out if I can run an appliance of mine can off the grid, completely on solar power and a battery.  The appliance uses 4.91 amps and uses 110 volts on the power cord.  The solar panel produces 45 watts of power.  The battery is a 12 Volt, 35 Ah Sealed Lead Acid Battery.  Now, I live in sunny FL, so sunlight shouldn't be an issue as it is sunny most of the time.  Will a single solar panel and battery be able to run it 24/7, without fail?  Meaning it must be able to run even when it dark out, cloudy, etc.  If my setup won't work, how many solar panels and batteries will I need?  Thank you in advance for your answers and advice.

Comment: The stack exchange websites are question and answer style and are not a general forum.  More particularly, the stack is for design issues and the details involved in electrical engineering.  You'd be better served at a DYI or Solar power forum.  I will note that 110 V * ~ 5 A = 550 W and your solar panel is only 45 watts.

Comment: Noting that the appliance needs 540W at least, there is a pretty good answer, explaining the issues and a methodology, already at [Powering 10watt light bulb for 24 hours using solar power](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/36280/9006)

Comment: What is the appliance, an air conditioner?

Answer (score 3):

4.91 amps at 110VAC is a power of 540 watts so no-matter how long a day it shines this won't work because average power in should exceed average power out by a few percent to account for conversion losses.

Your solar panel produces only 45 watts of power.

Now maybe you mean your appliance takes 4.91 amps from a 12V dc supply - this equates to a power of 59 watts and still you have a sizable deficit. Maybe your appiance uses a 5V supply at 4.91 amps? This is a power of 24.6 watts and I can see that with a little bit of clever design (sun tracking solar panel maybe) and a decent battery to power it thru the night) that this might work.

Comment: I downvoted you simply because this question doesn't belong here.  Why don't you try to contribute some of your time to _maintaining_ this site pruning these sorts of question out instead of fostering them?

Comment: @placeholder I disagree with you on all points in your comment.